# rest_no_route custom route

Tags: ajax, rest-api

I get a `rest_no_route` error if I try to use a custom endpoint I've created. Is there any solution? I'm creating my theme routes inside a plugin class, but I don't think this is a problem.
I'm using axios to get the data on front-end.

```
class theme_Rest_Routes extends WP_REST_Controller{

  public static function init()
  {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( __CLASS__, 'register_routes') );
  }

  public function register_routes()
  {
    register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/menu/', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => array(__CLASS__, 'theme_rest_menu'))
    );

  }

  public function theme_rest_menu( $request )
  {
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
  }

}
theme_Rest_Routes::init();
```

Comment: You don't need to subclass `WP_REST_Controller`, in fact in this situation it is either dead weight, or, causing harm as you don't use any of the Rest controller class. In both your question, and the answer below, you can delete `extends WP_REST_Controller` and it will work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are calling a static method from inside of a non-static method. The following will work.

```php
class theme_Rest_Routes extends WP_REST_Controller{

    public static function init() {
        $instance = new self();
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $instance, 'register_routes' ) );
    }

    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/menu/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'theme_rest_menu' ) )
        );
    }

    public function theme_rest_menu( $request ) {
        return wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu' );
    }
}
theme_Rest_Routes::init();
```

---

#### Code Improvement

You should not hook into `rest_api_init` from within the controller class itself, rather call it from an external class/function. Also class name should use capitalized words. As like below:

```php
function theme_register_rest_apis() {
    $controller = new Theme_Rest_Routes();
    $controller->register_routes();
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'theme_register_rest_apis' );

class Theme_Rest_Routes extends WP_REST_Controller{

    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route( 'theme/v1', '/menu/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'theme_rest_menu' ) )
        );
    }

    public function theme_rest_menu( $request ) {
        return wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu' );
    }
}
```